# SQL Temporary Added Count column to a returned set of results

Tags: sql, count, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following code that will join two different tables together and provide the discrete data columns that I need.  The issue is I also need a column that counts another instance from another table.  See pointer reference undernearth the select statement.

```
  SELECT 
  //count(of records returned from below query and duplicates of those found in outc table),
  outage_duration.dgroup,
  outage_duration.cause,
  outage_duration.cdts,
  outage_duration.cust_minutes,
  outage_duration.evntnum,
  outage_duration.num_cust,
  outage_duration.outage_type,
  outage_duration.substation,
  outage_duration.feeder,
  outage_duration.out_minutes
  FROM outage_duration,
  aeven
  WHERE outage_duration.evntnum    = aeven.num_1
  AND aeven.outage_type            = 'T'
  AND aeven.cdts                  >= '20110101060000UT'
  AND aeven.curent                 = 'T'
  AND aeven.open_and_curent        = 'F'
  AND aeven.ag_id NOT             IN    ('MEMT','MTRRDR','MTRTECH','GRDLT','FSRSR','ELECOPS','AMS','REVSEC')
  AND outage_duration.out_minutes >= '240'
  AND outage_duration.curent = 'T' 
  GROUP BY outage_duration.dgroup, outage_duration.cause, outage_duration.cdts, outage_duration.cust_minutes, outage_duration.evntnum, outage_duration.num_cust, outage_duration.outage_type, outage_duration.substation, outage_duration.feeder, outage_duration.out_minutes
  ORDER BY outage_duration.evntnum
```

Sample AEVEN, Outage_Duration table

```
num_1
T344490
T344410
T344480

outage_duration
T344490
T344410
```

This would return T344490 and T44410 which is what the above search does.  Now with these results I need to take a count from another table altogether and display the count as its own column beside the event number of how many occurences there were in that table.

outc (column 1 = unique id, column 2 = evntnum)

```
 1. 1, T344490
 2. 2, T344490
 3. 3, T344410
 4. 5, T344410
 5. 6, T344410
 6. 7, T344410
 7. 8, T344410
```

The desired results would like to be the following:

```
 1. T344410, 5, "other columns that were specified"
 2. T344490, 2, "other columns that were specified"
```

How would I manage to do this?

Comment: From sqldeveloper it auto added that when I copy pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*), --this
  outage_duration.dgroup,
  outage_duration.cause,
  outage_duration.cdts,
  outage_duration.cust_minutes,
  outage_duration.evntnum,
  outage_duration.num_cust,
  outage_duration.outage_type,
  outage_duration.substation,
  outage_duration.feeder,
  outage_duration.out_minutes
  FROM
      outage_duration
      JOIN
      aeven ON outage_duration.evntnum    = aeven.num_1
      JOIN
      outc ON outage_duration.evntnum = outc. --insert column here
  WHERE 
  AND aeven.outage_type            = 'T'
  AND aeven.cdts                  >= '20110101060000UT'
  AND aeven.curent                 = 'T'
  AND aeven.open_and_curent        = 'F'
  AND aeven.ag_id NOT             IN           ('MEMT','MTRRDR','MTRTECH','GRDLT','FSRSR','ELECOPS','AMS','REVSEC')
  AND outage_duration.out_minutes >= '240'
  AND outage_duration.curent = 'T' 
  GROUP BY outage_duration.dgroup, outage_duration.cause, outage_duration.cdts, outage_duration.cust_minutes, outage_duration.evntnum, outage_duration.num_cust, outage_duration.outage_type, outage_duration.substation, outage_duration.feeder, outage_duration.out_minutes
  ORDER BY outage_duration.evntnum
```

Just add a COUNT(*) to the SELECT bit, and the table outc to the FROM

You already have a GROUP BY so should just slot itn